# VBA MSHFLEXGRID wrong .ROW information in the CLICK event

Tags: vba, ms-access, mshflexgrid

I'm using the VBA MSHFLEXGRID, 2 grids in fact in the same Form, one below the other so when I choose a row in the first grid, the second one shows info regarding the first grid row selection.

Well, the problem is that the second grid, after choosing a row in the first grid which brings to no information in the second one (I put the data through the own grid recordset, and if i dont want it to show information, i do an exit in the load procedure, it gets crazy and the .ROW property in the Click event starts returning a fixed number, like for example 4, instead of the actual row being clicked. Always a number that represents a higher row than the last one (one that is even out of the grid). I tried also the .MOUSEROW and this one returns 0 all the time (when the grid becomes crazy).

This never happens with the first grid, only with the second one. There's nothing I can do without real information about the row being clicked. I've seen that with different resolutions the problem gets reset. Seems not to happen with low resolutions like 1360x768, but it does with 1920x1080 and 2560x1440.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! I was trying cases and more cases to try to understand why it happens sometimes in random cases and finally found it. The problem appears when you set the recordset directly to the grid (Set Grid.Recordset = xxxx) and this xxx is empty. It is, EOF. So I was doing a .Clearstructure, and then the SET. After this, if i did another SET (another selection of the second grid) with a non empty recordset, then it would go crazy.

So what I did was simple assigning first a recordset object to check if the SQL query is empty or not, and if it's not empty and only then, assign the recordset to the grid. Oh my god, this was bringing me crazy after a long time.